# Insert multiple arrays into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, dynamic-arrays

As an example, let's say I have three form text `inputs` all with the name `item[]`. Each of these `inputs` have a `value` consisting of two numbers separated by a comma.

```
<input type="text" name="item[]" value="8,6" />
<input type="text" name="item[]" value="6,1" />
<input type="text" name="item[]" value="9,4" />
```

The first number in the `value` field relates to an `id` in a mysql database table. The second is a value that will update another field.

I have used:

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $items){
    echo $items. "<br/>";
}
```

This displays the values like so:

```
8,6
6,1
9,4
```

I would now like to take these values and insert into a table with data fetched with the first value (the `id` value).

What would be the best way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: @sgt insert, sorry I said update but I meant insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, [explode](http://php.net/explode) **is** the best way. Try using it along with [list](http://php.net/list).

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $item){
    list($id, $value) = explode(',', $item);
}
```

Comment: This is easy to use with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($_POST['item'] as $items){
      $item = explode(",",$items);
      $id = $item[0];
      $otherfield = $item[1];

 //YOUR SQL QUERY with $id and $otherfield
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$values = array();
foreach($_POST['item'] as $items){
    $values[] = "(".$items.")"; 
}

$sql = "insert into `tablename` (`field1`, `field2`) values ".implode(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an one-liner without `foreach`.

```
//Warning this is unsafe to trust posted data.
$query = "INSERT INTO yourtable (id, otherfield) VALUES " . implode(',', array_map(function($v){return "($v)"; },$_POST['item']));
```

Note: NEVER trust posted data. You should always sanitize and validate the data before updating to database. Also try to use prepared statements whenever possible

Reference: [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: I only use prepared statements when there is post or get data in the equation, thanks, I'll give it a bash

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `id` is the primary key of your table, I'd use an efficient way to add or update selected rows with specific ids. As mentioned before, you should use a combination of explode and list to extract what you need and build sql query.

```
//assuming you don't already have a db connection
//fill constants yourself with apropriate connection info
$dbConnection =  mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 

foreach($_POST['item'] as $item){
   list($id, $value) = explode(',', $item);

   //prevent inserting empty values (assuming that 0 is not allowed)
   if (!empty($id) && !empty($value)) {

      //remember escaping - prevent from SQL injection!
      $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($id); 
      $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$value}')
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value='{$value}'";
      mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);
   }
}
```